# Why are t.u.p groups torsion-free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I am new here so apologies if this is a dumb question. But I have recently encountered the idea of a two unique product group (t.u.p group). We take a group $G$ with two subsets $X, Y$. An element $g\in G$ can represented as a product in $X$ and $Y$ if $g=xy$ where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. It is represented uniquely if $g=x^\prime y^\prime$ $x^\prime\in X$, $y^\prime\in Y$ implies $x=x^\prime$, $y=y^\prime$. We suppose $|X|\geq 2$ and $|Y|\geq 2$ and then say $G$ is a t.u.p group if at least two elements can be represented uniquely in $X$ and $Y$. Now I have read in plenty of places that these groups must be torsion-free. Why is this? Perhaps I am not understanding the definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "at least two elements can be represented uniquely in $X$ and $Y$"? Can you please state the exact definition you have read?

Comment: @cronos2 Sorry, hope this is clearer.

Comment: How about $G = \Bbb Z_5, X = \{1, 2\} = Y$. Then $2 = 1+1, 4 = 2+2$ are uniquely represented but obviously $G$ is torsion *full*

Comment: @cronos2 Yes, this is my problem. I've been wondering if I am missing something obvious. I found this page which deals with these groups and again mentions the fact these cannot have torsion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207996/u-p-unique-product-group-which-is-not-right-ordered-ro

Comment: Well, there you go: "Similarly, a two unique product group , (t.u.p group) is a group $G$ such that if given any two finite non empty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $G$ with $|A|+|B|>2$ [...]", which is a much stronger condition.

Comment: @cronos2 How so?

Comment: Oh wait, am I being an idiot. The definition is saying for any two finite subsets, so I could always take $\{g, g^2\}$ and $\{1, g^{-1}\}$ so $g^2\cdot g^{-1}=g=g\cdot 1\}$?

Comment: no, because then $g^2 = g^2 \cdot 1, 1 = g \cdot g^{-1}$ are uniquely represented and the hypothesis holds.

Comment: However, consider $X = \{0, 1, 4\}, Y = \{0, 2, 4\}$ for the $\Bbb Z_5$ example. Then $0 + 0 = 1 + 4, 0 + 4 = 4 + 0, 1 + 0 = 4 + 2, 1 + 2 = 4 + 4$ and only $0 + 2$ is unique.

Comment: @cronos2 Ah yes, of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $G$ is a t.u.p. group and denote its identity element by $e$.

Seeking a contradiction, suppose that $G$ is not torsion-free. First notice that $G$ cannot be a trivial group. By our assumption there is some non-identity $g\in G$ and a natural number $n$ such that $g^n=e$.

Now, consider the cyclic subgroup $X=\{e,g,\ldots,g^{n-1}\}$ of $G$. Put $Y=X$ and notice that they are finite sets. Obviously, $XY=X$ but there is no element of $X$ that can be uniquely written as a product of an element of $X$ and an element of $Y$. This shows that $G$ is not a u.p. group (thus not a t.u.p. group) and gives us a contradiction.